# Hide link from screenreaders, but show text

Tags: html, wai-aria

I run a legal website where we have text like this:

> As was said in 22 U.S. 44, blah, blah

Then later, somebody will refer to the citation with:

> And yes, donuts are good, Id at 54.

When we do this, we make both `22 U.S. 44` (the original citation) and `Id at 54` into links.

For folks using screen readers, this is annoying because we make a LOT of links. Is there a way to show the text of the "Id" links, but make them not look like links to screen readers?

Comment: Maybe use `role="none"`? https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#none

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough this is a topic that's recently [been added for acceptance review](https://github.com/w3c/aria/issues/1044) of better ways to handle repetition scenarios. Since in general there's more emphasis on [handling navigation blocks](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-skip.html) than just repeated navigation as content

Personally I usually opt to provide [aria-label](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-label_for_link_purpose) with repetition of the link text and negate the href with `role="presentation"` and works decent with many SR's but I don't believe there's an ideal solution for the instance as of yet.

Comment: Would doing role=presentation would be bad for those actually reading through the text? I.e., would they miss the link entirely, to their detriment? I'm gathering that's the compromise that needs to be made here? Thanks for information.

Comment: @mlissner presentation/none only removes the semantic context of the elements it's used on and their children (unless designated otherwise) so for instance if I did `<p role="presentation">...` then an SR would/should still read the textual content but not announce it as it would a paragraph. In this scenario an SR would/should read the textual content of the label (or textual content of the hyperlink) without announcing as a link.